# How do you I get a user_impersonation token from an app-only token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net

So there are some APIs in Azure that work fine when I use my logged in access token. But they just won't work with the app-only token issued to my app.

During onboarding of our multi-tenant Azure app the administrator consents/approves access into their tenant, which requests a set of permissions including:

- Read directory data
- Access the directory as the signed-in user

For everything up to now, this was good enough. When our Azure Function needs to act on behalf of the admin we can call AcquireTokenAsync() to get the app-only token and use it to query the resources we need.

However, we have come across some resources that give us a 400 error saying `"AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in."`.

In these situations where it needs a signed-in user token (and we can't get one as its a backend function doing automated processing after hours), what are we supposed to do? I don't want to have to store the user's credentials in KeyVault to do a password auth to get such a token. The whole point of using app-only tokens was to avoid this.

What are we supposed to do in this situation?

Comment: I'm confused: do I understand that the Web API requires a refresh token?

Comment: please go through all the guides regarding [multi-tenant applications here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/setup-multi-tenant-app) and the guide about [application permissions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent). At the end make sure you have read and understood [Azure AD Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios). Then please come back here and rephrase your question.

Comment: Updated question to more clearly explain what it is that we are coming across.

Comment: If you've never authenticated as an end user to acquire first token for a backend API to call the further APIs (because you say it's a backend Azure function so no user interaction) then AFAIK you will not be able to use On Behalf Of flow to get user_impersonation token. Please include the full code that you're using to acquire app-only token and make further calls. Looking at the error you're probably not using correct ADAL overload to acquire token using application's identity.. and trying to get the token in User's context.. that's just a guess..

Comment: We authenticate the user in a web app the first time they login. It redirects to Microsoft's IdP to do OAUTH consent which in turn registers our app in their tenant, gives us perms to their subscription, creates the service principal and then redirects back. At this point, we can use our app to access their tenant. This follows Microsoft guidance on using multitenant apps with app-only tokens.

Comment: On the adal constructor, we are using AcquireTokenAsync(resource, Client Credentials). Which overload are you thinking is supposed to be used?

Comment: ADAL method you mention looks correct for acquiring token using app identity. Which resource/api is it that you're trying to access when you get the error AADSTS50058? Also, I hope you selected "Read Directory Data" under    application permissions and not delegated permissions section, because it's available in both. I say this because you're trying to use app token.

Comment: I've selected the read under both application and delegated.

Comment: The resource I am trying to access is https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/ApplicationProxy/TenantSettings, which I've tried access directly and through the reserved GUID of 74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6. More info can be found from articles like [this](http://devchat.live/en/2018/01/10/how-to-call-rest-apis-on-azure-portal/).

Comment: BTW, there are several other pieces of data I would like to read under this reserved GUID. The example uses password grant_type, which I want to avoid, as I do not wish to ask the customer to give me their Azure password. So the purpose of this is to find a way to access 74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6 correctly with an app-only token.

Comment: I understand the requirement more clearly now.. although as the blog says itself there isn't any valid API to access this resource.. so it uses password grant.. if there aren't any relevant `application permissions` to be used, then app-token will not work. I can't be absolutely sure because haven't worked with this resource before. On a side note, you should edit your question and include some of this information.. you will probably get better answers that way.